# wordpress the_content is overlap navigation

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress page content and title is overlap the navigation. 
navigation is inside the header, and the page content and title is on template file and I style the header, but nothing happen.
This is my problem:
[pic of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sfie.png)

and my Template code:

```
  <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
              <hr />
              <span class="logo-intro"><?php the_content(); ?></span>
            <?php endwhile; endif;?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

my header.php code:

```
<header id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default site-nav id="topNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <span class="logo-intro">Finspired Partners-yksilöllistä brandikonsultointia
          <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/Assets/logo.png" class="company-logo" alt="logo" />
        </span>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler toggle-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">☰</span>
        </button>
        <?php
          wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'container' => false,
                'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
                'depth' => 2,
                'container' => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id' => 'collapsibleNavbar',
                'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav mt-2 mt-md-0, nav-item active nav-list, nav-link nav-a ',
                'walker' => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(),
                    'fallback_cb' => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback'
              )
            );
        ?>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <li class="nav-item active nav-list">
              <a class="nav-link nav-a" href="#"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Can someone help me to find the solution ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `</header>` after `</nav>`.

Because `<header>` is not closed. So Content start in `header` file.

Otherwise provide Your Live Link.